# Nginx Redirection of Jenkins on Kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I am trying to deploy Jenkins on Kubernetes. I have deployed it with ClusterIP along with Nginx Ingress Controller on AKS.

When I access the IP of the Ingress-Controller, the Jenkins login URL (http://*ExternalIP*/login?from=%2F) comes up. However the UI of the Jenkins page isn't coming up and there is a some sort of redirection happening and keeps growing (http://*ExternalIP*/login?from=%2F%3Ffrom%3D%252F%253Ffrom%253D%25252F%25253F). I am very new to Ingress controller and annotations. I am not able to figure on what's causing this redirection.

Below are my configuration files. Can anyone please help on what's going wrong ?

**ClusterIP-Service.yml**

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: jenkins-nodeport-svc
  namespace: jenkins
  labels:
    env: poc
    app: myapp_jenkins
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "http"
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
      app: myapp_jenkins
```

**Ingress.yml**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: jenkins-ingress
  namespace: jenkins
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: Authorization, origin, accept
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: GET, OPTIONS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"

spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
       - backend:
          serviceName: jenkins-nodeport-svc
          servicePort: 80
         path: /(.*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something in your ingress:

```
path: /(.*)
```

is a regular expression with a single capturing group that match everything. For example with following url: `http://ExternalIP/login?from=myurl` your capturing group `$1` (the first and only one) would match `login?from/myurl`.

Now the problem is that `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2` annotation is rewriting your url with a non existing capturing group.

You don't need rewriting, you just need to plain forward every request to the service.
[Here you can find Rewrite Examples](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#rewrite-target) if you interested on it.

But in your case you can set:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: jenkins-ingress
  namespace: jenkins
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: Authorization, origin, accept
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: GET, OPTIONS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"

spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
       - backend:
          serviceName: jenkins-nodeport-svc
          servicePort: 80
         path: /
```

and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you so much on the explanation! It solved my issue. Even better, thanks for sharing the link to rewrites. Now, I have a better clarity on what I am doing :) Cheers!